# Recover tasks from a deleted workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, restore

I just made a new version of a Workflow, and so that users would not get confused I deleted the old one, but that also deleted all the task that were created by it. I tried restoring the Workflow from the recycle bin, but that didn't restore the previus tasks.

It is possible to restore these tasks? or where they permanently deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know these have been permanently deleted, however if you do routine back ups of your site you should be able to restore it to an earlier date and retrieve the items that way.

Comment: sorry for the late answer, It is like that, thanks!